# Server.ScriptTimeout not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a vb.net page that runs on a button a function that builds excel templates. if the page runs less then 90 seconds the page updates with a download link. if it errors at any point it will show the error in a box.
the script runs always reguardless of time but the browser only updates if within 90 seconds. if the page takes longer the browser does not update.

I put in database logging of each step so I know my function runs all the way through.
I have executionTimeout="1200" in the web.config and also tried Server.ScriptTimeout = 1200 in the page load and in the first line of the function.

as I said the function does run and no timeout error but the browser does not update.

Answer (score 0):

friend of mine said to try a tag in scriptmanager because it's timeout is 90 seconds. so I added  AsyncPostBackTimeout="1200" to the scriptmanager and that fixed my issue.